# Does $0\to L_1\to \tilde{V}\to L_2\to 0$ restrict on a subspace $S$ to $0\to L_1|_S \to \tilde{V}|_S \to L_2|_S\to 0$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, exact-sequence, fibration

**My question:**

Take a manifold $Z$, and let $S\subset Z$ be a submanifold of $Z$ (with the subspace topology).

Let $V$, $V'$, and $V''$ be vector bundles on $Z$, with projections $\pi:V \to Z$ etc.

Write $V|_S$ for the restriction of the bundle $V$ to $\pi^{-1}(S)$, with the restricted projection $\pi_S: V|_S \to S$. That is, $V|_S$ is the pullback bundle $i^* V$, where $i: S \to Z$ is the inclusion. Then $V|_S$ is a vector bundle over $S$. Similarly for $V'|_S$ and $V''|_S$.

Suppose now that we have a vector bundle map $u:V \to V'$. That is, suppose $u: V \to V'$ is a continuous map and that the following diagram commutes,
$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\,\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\,\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\begin{array}{c}
V & \ra{~~~u~~~} & V'  \\
\da{\pi} & & \da{\pi'} \\
Z & \ras{~~~\text{Id}~~~} & Z \\
\end{array}
$$

I believe this induces a vector bundle map $\tilde{u}:V|_S \to V'|_S$, simply by restricting all four maps. (More generally, I imagine it is the case that a vector bundle map $u: E \to E'$, where $E$ and $E'$ are vector bundles over $X$ and $Y$, induces a vector bundle map $\tilde{u} : f^*E \to f^*E'$,  for any continuous map $f: X \to Y$ between the base spaces. But I have not seen a proof of this.)

Now suppose we have a short exact sequence
$$0 \to V \xrightarrow{\,f\,} V' \xrightarrow{\,g\,}  V'' \to 0$$
of vector bundles on $Z$. My question is whether this induces a short exact sequence for the vector bundles on $S\subset Z$,
$$0 \to V|_S \xrightarrow{\,\tilde{f}\,} V'|_S \xrightarrow{\,\tilde{g}\,}  V''|_S \to 0 \, .$$

---

**My reasoning:**

I believe that the answer to this question is affirmative, and my reasoning is as follows. Please let me know if anything here is incorrect.

Since $\tilde{f}$ is the restriction of an injective map $f$, it too is injective.

As $g$ is surjective, and since points in $\pi''^{-1}(S)$ can only be mapped to from $\pi'^{-1}(S)$ (because of the commutative diagram condition, which enforces that a point in a fibre over a point $x\in Z$ in the base is mapped to a point in a fibre over the same point), $\tilde{g}:\pi'^{-1}(S)\to\pi''^{-1}(S)$ is also surjective.

To show the sequence is exact, all that remains is to show $\text{Im}(\tilde{f})=\text{Ker}(\tilde{g})$. For this we can note that
$$\text{Im}(\tilde{f})=\text{Im}(f)\,\cap\,\pi'^{-1}(S)\, ,$$
$$\text{Ker}(\tilde{g})=\text{Ker}(g)\,\cap\,\pi'^{-1}(S)\, .$$
(The second is I think obvious. The first is perhaps more difficult to see, but again seems to follow from the fact that a fibre over $x\in Z$ is mapped to another fibre over the same point.) Hence since $\text{Im}(f)=\text{Ker}(g)$, we have that $\text{Im}(\tilde{f})=\text{Ker}(\tilde{g})$.

So it seems that we have induced a short exact sequence on the subspace $S$.

---

**My specific interest:**

In particular, I'm interested in showing that a short exact sequence $0 \to V \to V' \to V'' \to 0$ on an elliptic fibration $Z$ induces a short exact sequence $0 \to V|_{E_b} \to V'|_{E_b} \to V''|_{E_b} \to 0$ on each elliptic curve $E_b$ ($b\in Z$).

More specifically, I would like to show that if we begin with a non-trivial extension on $Z$ then we get non-trivial extensions on each elliptic curve $E_b$.

Comment: Exactness is something you can check on fibers and the fiber of $V$ at a point $x \in S$ is the same as the fiber of $V|_S$, isn't it?

Comment: @Hoot: Am I correct in thinking you're saying the following? There is a result showing that "If we have vector bundle maps giving a sequence $0 \to V \to V' \to V'' \to 0$, then the sequence is exact if and only if it gives a short exact sequence on each fibre". Then we can go from the global SES to the fibre SES's (using the 'only if') and then back up to the SES for the vector bundles on the subspace $S$ (using the 'if'), giving the desired result. (If so, could you perhaps link me to a statement of the result I put in quotes above?)